# How to fix this JavaScript accordion error?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been asked to create a new information page for our website and would like to place the information in an accordion to make it easier on the end users eye however I cannot get the script to work on the buttons could someone help me, please?

FYI I have no experience with JS and am really just a beginner with HTML & CSS.

Thanks,
Jack

I have moved the script tag into the body tag and have renamed the function to the accordion.

```
<style>
    /* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */

    .accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    }

    /* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
    .active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
    .panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .accordion:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
    }
</style>

<head>
    <div></div>Our top Delivery/Returns FAQ’s
        <p>We work hard to deliver your items as quickly as possible and offer a fuss-free returns process.</p>
        <p> Below are some of our top FAQ’s but if you have any further questions please contact us on +44 (0) 20 3946 3795 or help@fiorucci.com</p>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="accordion" onclick="accordion()">How much is delivery?</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Delivery Location</td>
                <td>Delivery Charge</td>
                <td>Expected Delivery Timing</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>UK Standard Delivery</td>
                <td>£3.95 (Free over £50)</td>
                <td>2-3 working days</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>We also offer international shipping to over 100 countries from our local sites for Europe and USA.</p>  
        <p>Please use our USA site for worldwide shipping, you can see a full list of all countries here
        </p>
    </div>

    <button onclick="accordion()" class="accordion">How do I track my order?</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>When your order's ready to leave our warehouse we'll email to let you know. Then you can Track your order for regular updates</p>
            Only just ordered? You can check your order status and contact details in My Account.</p>
            Don’t forget that our couriers work ‘til 9pm so your order could arrive in the evening. If you're not in when the courier tries to deliver don't panic! You will receive a notification with further instructions</p>
    </div>

    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="accordion">Do I need to sign for my delivery?</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>All orders sent by DHL require a signature on delivery but this is not a named service which means that your order does not have to be signed for specifically by you.</p>
        <p>We will not be liable for any lost or missing orders that have been signed for at the delivery address</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Can I cancel or amend my order?</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>Cancellation: We can attempt to cancel your order within 60 minutes of placing, please call us to request this on +44 (0)203 946 3795 but this can't be guaranteed. After this time we can't cancel before delivery, but you can return unworn items for free within 14 days of receiving your order.</p>
    <p>If you believe that your delivery address is incorrect please call us ASAP. Address changes cannot be guaranteed however will be attempted.</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Do you offer weekend delivery?</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>DHL don’t deliver on weekends or bank holidays but you can divert your delivery to one of over 1,000 service points across the UK to make your delivery easy.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", 
        function accordion() {
            /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
            to highlight the button that controls the panel */
            this.classList.toggle("active");

            /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
            } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Expected result: Open and closing of accorion on FE

Actual result: CTA doesnt action accordion script

Thanks again, 
Jack

Comment: Your html is invalid - you cannot put elements in the head (and you have an extra closing div tag too just for good measure).  The head is for your style tags and links / js and document title

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your HTML. As Pete mentions in a comment, you should not put elements in the [head tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head). I have also remove the `onclick` attributes from each button, you are already adding event listeners in your javascript. You were missing a `}` to close the for loop so I have added that in and also pulled your `accordion()` declaration outside of the for loop.

```js
function accordion() {
  /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
  to highlight the button that controls the panel */
  this.classList.toggle("active");

  /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
  var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.style.display === "block") {
    panel.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    panel.style.display = "block";
  }
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", accordion);
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Our top Delivery/Returns FAQ’s
    <p>We work hard to deliver your items as quickly as possible and offer a fuss-free returns process.</p>
    <p> Below are some of our top FAQ’s but if you have any further questions please contact us on +44 (0) 20 3946 3795 or help@fiorucci.com</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">How much is delivery?</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Delivery Location</td>
        <td>Delivery Charge</td>
        <td>Expected Delivery Timing</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>UK Standard Delivery</td>
        <td>£3.95 (Free over £50)</td>
        <td>2-3 working days</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>We also offer international shipping to over 100 countries from our local sites for Europe and USA.</p>
    <p>Please use our USA site for worldwide shipping, you can see a full list of all countries here
    </p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">How do I track my order?</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>When your order's ready to leave our warehouse we'll email to let you know. Then you can Track your order for regular updates</p>
    Only just ordered? You can check your order status and contact details in My Account.</p>
    Don’t forget that our couriers work ‘til 9pm so your order could arrive in the evening. If you're not in when the courier tries to deliver don't panic! You will receive a notification with further instructions</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Do I need to sign for my delivery?</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>All orders sent by DHL require a signature on delivery but this is not a named service which means that your order does not have to be signed for specifically by you.</p>
    <p>We will not be liable for any lost or missing orders that have been signed for at the delivery address</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Can I cancel or amend my order?</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Cancellation: We can attempt to cancel your order within 60 minutes of placing, please call us to request this on +44 (0)203 946 3795 but this can't be guaranteed. After this time we can't cancel before delivery, but you can return unworn items for
      free within 14 days of receiving your order.</p>
    <p>If you believe that your delivery address is incorrect please call us ASAP. Address changes cannot be guaranteed however will be attempted.</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Do you offer weekend delivery?</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>DHL don’t deliver on weekends or bank holidays but you can divert your delivery to one of over 1,000 service points across the UK to make your delivery easy.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you are a beginner... have you heared of the console?
If you open up the developer toolbar (see instructions for [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open), [FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console), [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console), [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/)) you will see your code was generating some errors.

**The JS errors**

First of all it stated: ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at line 112.*** 
It turns out you missed a closing bracket there. The "for" loop was opened but not closed. This is where proper indentations helps a lot to spot mistakes.

When clicking the first button, console tells me: ***Uncaught ReferenceError: accordion is not defined***.
I notice you have 'onclick' attributes on the buttons, but also listen to the click events in JS. It is best to only use one of these two methods. I prefer the last one. 
Once I removed the onclick items all worked fine without any errors.

**Your page structure**

I see your page does not really adhere to standards as far as structure. As it is now, it might work in some browsers, but there's no guarantee. 
Have a look at this article for a basic html5 structure. 
https://www.sitepoint.com/a-basic-html5-template/

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
   acc[i].addEventListener("click", function accordion() {
     // Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
     // to highlight the button that controls the panel
     this.classList.toggle("active");

     // Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
     var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
     if (panel.style.display === "block") {
       panel.style.display = "none";
     } else {
       panel.style.display = "block";
     }
   });
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel*/
.accordion {
   background-color: #eee;
   color: #444;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 18px;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: left;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   transition: 0.4s;
}

/*Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on 
(add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse 
over it (hover)*/
.active, 
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: white;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
<head>
    <div></div>Our top Delivery/Returns FAQ’s
        <p>We work hard to deliver your items as quickly as possible and offer a fuss-free returns process.</p>
        <p> Below are some of our top FAQ’s but if you have any further questions please contact us on +44 (0) 20 3946 3795 or help@fiorucci.com</p>
    </div>
</head>
    <button class="accordion" >How much is delivery?</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Delivery Location</td>
                <td>Delivery Charge</td>
                <td>Expected Delivery Timing</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>UK Standard Delivery</td>
                <td>£3.95 (Free over £50)</td>
                <td>2-3 working days</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>We also offer international shipping to over 100 countries from our local sites for Europe and USA.</p>
        <p>Please use our USA site for worldwide shipping, you can see a full list of all countries here
        </p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">How do I track my order?</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>When your order's ready to leave our warehouse we'll email to let you know. Then you can Track your order for regular updates</p>
            Only just ordered? You can check your order status and contact details in My Account.</p>
            Don’t forget that our couriers work ‘til 9pm so your order could arrive in the evening. If you're not in when the courier tries to deliver don't panic! You will receive a notification with further instructions</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Do I need to sign for my delivery?</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>All orders sent by DHL require a signature on delivery but this is not a named service which means that your order does not have to be signed for specifically by you.</p>
        <p>We will not be liable for any lost or missing orders that have been signed for at the delivery address</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Can I cancel or amend my order?</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>Cancellation: We can attempt to cancel your order within 60 minutes of placing, please call us to request this on +44 (0)203 946 3795 but this can't be guaranteed. After this time we can't cancel before delivery, but you can return unworn items for free within 14 days of receiving your order.</p>
    <p>If you believe that your delivery address is incorrect please call us ASAP. Address changes cannot be guaranteed however will be attempted.</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Do you offer weekend delivery?</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>DHL don’t deliver on weekends or bank holidays but you can divert your delivery to one of over 1,000 service points across the UK to make your delivery easy.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will take that on board. So you would recommend editing code in my software, saving the changes and the experimenting using the browser console for further changes I want to make?

Comment: @JackTaylor You should always keep an eye on console when working with javascript. Make your changes then check console for any errors/warnings if it's not working as expected.

Comment: @Jack Taylor not so much experimenting using the console, more checking the console for errors/warnings. 

When things don't work the way you expect, you can drop some console.log()`s in your code to see what gets executed, in what order etc. 

Coding javascript without a console to me is like painting with a blindfold on.